# What's wrong with this argument for CON(ZFC)?

Tags: lo.logic

> If a $\Pi_1$ sentence is independent from PA, then it is true.
> CON(ZFC) is a $\Pi_1$ sentence and independent from PA.
> Therefore, CON(ZFC).

If this is a valid argument in ZFC, it would violate Gödel's incompleteness theorem. What's wrong with it?

Comment: You did not even give a single bit of justification for your claim that Con(ZFC) is independent from PA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if CON(FZC) is false, then it is not independent of PA - as PA can look at the ZFC-proof of falsity and confirm it.